# Laptop making low-pitched, humming noises when turned off but not unplugged (Lenovo IdeaPad 100)

Tags: power-supply, lenovo-laptop

I recently bought a new [Lenovo IdeaPad 100 15''](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/100-series/100-15-inch/#80MJ0018US) and the problem is that when it's turned off, but not unplugged (meaning, the power cord is attached to the wall socket and one of the LEDs is still lit indicating that the laptop is plugged to the electrical power source), it's making barely audible (you can definitely hear it though), kind of scratching, humming noises like there is something inside it still working. However, when you detach the power cord from the wall socket, it then does power off completely making the noises go away. I have never worked with Lenovo computers before, but do you think that's normal with Lenovo laptops?

Comment: Sounds like there could be a problem with the electrical currents. Is the IdeaPad using the correct power cord? If not, that could be putting more current through the device than there is supposed to be? Have you run diagnostics on it?

Comment: I'm using the cord that came with the laptop. I didn't do anything at all with the computer.

Comment: Have you run diagnostics? Does this happen on different power outlets?

Comment: Have you tried to wiggle the power connection at the laptop? Does it persist then? Also, (and may be hard to tell) is the noise coming from the speakers?

Comment: No, I have not run any diagnostics. And this most definitely has nothing to do with the outlet itself. I actually have an extension cord plugged right to it that has a bunch of other devices hooked up.

Comment: I have tried to wiggle the power cord. That obviously is not what causes this noise. And I think the noise is coming from the back of the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you've just bought your computer and you still have your warranty, with problems related to a faulty piece of hardware or just you feel that something is not quite right, your best option would be to call one of your manufacturer's service centers available in your city and bring it back to them which is exactly what I did. They said that the AC adapter is indeed probably broken and they will replace it with a new one after they run some diagnostics on it. This may take a while though depending on whether they have it in stock. If not, they will order one for me.